# A basic question of basic writing

Tags: notation, article-writing

When we define some term by a notation starting with the word "define" or "let", which of the following is correct?

Define $A=x+2y$; or, define $A \equiv x+2y$.

Comment: Did you mean the $:=$ symbol? If so, I think you need to write in a new command in latex.. See here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28836/typesetting-the-define-equals-symbol

Comment: Actually, I was just wondering if we use the equality sign or equivalence sign.

Comment: I don't think it would be wise to use $\equiv$, which almost always means modular equivalence. Simple $=$ is correct, and Grigory Ilizirov gives several other options.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, many sign than look like equation is usually used for definitions:

---

Equivalence  $\equiv$, also used for congruence in geometry.
 
Assignment signs =:, :=, used is computer science to indicate assignment 
 
Logical equivalence  :⇔
 
Define sign ≜, usually used in physics 
 
And the most obvious: ≝ , (I personally recommend)

But it is not necessary if you write the world "define" before, just use $=$

Comment: I sometimes use $::=$

Comment: `\stackrel` can be useful here.  For example `\stackrel\Delta=` is $\stackrel\Delta=$.